# Changing the number of divisions in graph scale

Tags: visio

I'm having a little problem with graph scale in visio. My goal for now is to make a graph scale (belongs to charting shapes) with 22 divisions in it. But I don't know how to add an option of 22 divisions on the scale (2, 4 and 5 division options are available). 
[image: Graph scale]

I have tried to add 22 division option in "Define Shape Data" window, but unlucky.
[image: define shape data]

I have searched whole internet for the solution, but I found no solution.
I hope someone here will know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding 22 to the options will not magically make 22 divisions appear. You will also need to have the shapes (or geometry sections) behind it (22 of them, not just 2, 4 or 5) to be made visible when 22 is selected.

You need to understand how the whole shape is constructed, by looking at the various group sub-shapes (and/or geometry sections) to see how each is made visible/invisible when the 2/4/5 selection is made.